# Conf.py not getting my DRF project's settings

Tags: django-rest-framework, python-sphinx

I have a existing project based on Django Rest Framework. I want to document it using sphinx but I'm stuck at configuring Sphinx. My project structure goes like this:

- myProject

  - apps folder

    - users
    - designers
  - settings

    - base.py
    - development.py
  - docs #sphinx folder

    - conf.py #and other *.rst

Content of conf.py goes like this:

```
import sys
import os
import django
from django.conf import settings

sys.path.insert(os.path.abspath('../myProject/settings') # project settings path

settings.configure() #I also tried DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = myProject.settings or myProject.base both cases doesn't work
django.setup()
```

Content of index.rst is simple just calling the user module while running 
`sphinx-apidoc command -F -o source dest` but it is still giving me no module named users error.

Comment: Apps and Settings are folder and Users and base.py are one level deep in it. Typo error while posting the question

Comment: Please edit the question if there are typos.

Comment: edited the structure of the project.